# Laravel Collection Diff not returning difference between two collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I am trying to get difference between two collection with diff function of laravel,but do not know why it always return 0 difference items, although $col1 contains 6 items and $col2 contain 5 items,
My code:

```
$col1=collect([$data['result']->items()]);
$col2=collect([$data['erp_data']]);
$diff=$col1->diff($col2);
dd($col1,$col2,$diff);
```

and it returns

[image: result]

Help needed,thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [compare two collection arrays in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61069470/2943403)

Answer (score 5):

The 2 collections are the same. It's an array with one item, that contains another array inside it. The `diff` method compares the collection to see the main elements and finds that both are arrays with 1 element. Which is why there is no diff.

You should remove the surrounding square brackets `[]` on your collection creation.

ie. `$col2 = collect($data['erp_data']);`